# how to do gridspec in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am doing Matplotlib gridspec plots with Bokeh. 
In my problem, there are 2 columns and 2 lines. Each column on the first line contains one plot and only one plot that merge the 2 columns on the second line.

this is my code with Matplotlib

```
def test_gridspec_2rows_2cols():
    NROWS = 2; NCOLS = 2;
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(100,3)), columns=list("abc"))
    df = df.reset_index()
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=NCOLS, nrows=NROWS, figure=fig)
    f_ax00 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
    f_ax00.set_title("gs[0,0]")
    f_ax01 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
    f_ax01.set_title("gs[0,1]")
    f_ax02 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:])
    f_ax02.set_title("gs[1,:]")
    df.plot(x="index", y='a', ax=f_ax00)
    df.plot(x="index", y='b', ax=f_ax01)
    df.plot(x="index", y='c', ax=f_ax02)
```

here is my training code in Bokeh

```
def test_bokeh_2rows_2cols():
    # configuration figure
    output_file("test_dashboard.html")
    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select,lasso_select"
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=(100,3)), columns=list("abc"))
    src = ColumnDataSource(df)
    p_cols = []
    p_a = figure(plot_height=200, plot_width=200, title="A", tools=TOOLS)
    p_a.line(source=src, x='a', y='a')
    p_b = figure(plot_height=200, plot_width=200, title="B", tools=TOOLS)
    p_b.line(source=src, x='b', y='b')
    p_c = figure(plot_height=200, plot_width=200, title="C", tools=TOOLS)
    p_c.line(source=src, x='c', y='c')
    p_cols.append([p_a, p_b])
    p_cols.append([p_c])
    p =  gridplot(p_cols)
    show(p)
```

The result on Bokeh plot is different on my matplotlib plot.

Comment: What result do you except?

Comment: The plot on the second line i.e p_c is on the column one but doesn't merge the two columns.